# Find the values of $x$ in terms of $a$ in $x^2+\frac{(ax)^2} {(x+a)^2} =3a^2$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, contest-math, roots, quadratics, factoring

The question is as follows.

> Find the values of $x$ in terms of $a$ in
>
> $x^2+\dfrac{(ax)^2}{(x+a)^2} =3a^2 $

My solution:

Multiply both sides by $(x+a)^2$ and expand. On rearranging we get

$x^4+2ax^3-a^2x^2-6a^3x-3a^4=0$

Now dividing by $a^4$ we and taking $\dfrac{x}{a}=y$, we get

$y^4+2y^3-y^2-6y^3-3=0$

Now we can write the above equation as

$(y^2+ay+b)(y^2+cy+d)=0$

Now expanding it and comparing coefficient with the equation we get

$a=-1;b=-1;c=3;d=3$

So we get

$(y^2-y-1)(y^2 +3y+3)=0$

The second bracket has no real roots and by solving 1st bracket we get

$y=\dfrac{x}{a} =\dfrac{1\pm\sqrt5}{2}$

So $x=\dfrac{a(1\pm\sqrt5) }{2}$

My question is

1: As you can see the method is long and tedious, is there any other or elegant way to solve it?

2:Can any step in my solution or the solution itself be improved upon or be replaced by another easier step (like but **not limited** to factorising the equation we got in $y$ directly into two quadratics or solving the quatic directly)

Thanks!

I got the question from a preparatory book for olympiads.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's $$x^2+\frac{a^2x^2}{(x+a)^2}-\frac{2ax^2}{a+x}+\frac{2ax^2}{a+x}=3a^2$$ or
$$\left(x-\frac{ax}{a+x}\right)^2+\frac{2ax^2}{a+x}=3a^2$$ or
$$\left(\frac{x^2}{a+x}\right)^2+\frac{2ax^2}{a+x}-3a^2=0$$ or
$$\left(\frac{x^2}{a+x}\right)^2+\frac{2ax^2}{a+x}+a^2-a^2-3a^2=0$$
 or
$$\left(\frac{x^2}{a+x}+a\right)^2-(2a)^2=0$$
or
$$\left(\frac{x^2}{a+x}-a\right)\left(\frac{x^2}{a+x}+3a\right)=0$$ and the rest is smooth:

The domain gives $x\neq-a$, which gives $a\neq0.$

Thus, $$x^2+3ax+3a^2=\left(x+\frac{3a}{2}\right)^2+\frac{3a^2}{4}>0,$$ which says that the right polynomial does not give roots.

Also, $$x^2-ax-a^2=0$$ gives
$$\left\{\frac{a(1+\sqrt5)}{2},\frac{a(1-\sqrt5)}{2}\right\}.$$
To solve an equation with parameter says to solve this equation for any values of the parameter.

Id est, we got the following answer.

If $a=0$, so $\oslash$;

if $a\neq0$, so $\left\{\frac{a(1+\sqrt5)}{2},\frac{a(1-\sqrt5)}{2}\right\}.$

Comment: Thanks! Your solution seems very easy.

Comment: @Satwik You are welcome!

Answer (score 0):

Rewrite and factorize the equation as

$$\begin{align}
0 & = x^2(x+a)^2+(ax)^2 -3a^2 (x+a)^2\\
& = x^4+2x^3a+2x^2a^2 -3a^2 (x+a)^2 \\
& = x^4+2x^2a(x+a)-3a^2 (x+a)^2 \\
& = (x^2-a(x+a)) (x^2+3a(x+a))\\
\end{align}$$